# wrap the line from <div contenteditable=true> with <p> tag in keyup/keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While typing content in `<div contenteditable=true id='edited_content>`, find whether the line have `<p>` tag if not wrap it with `<p>` tag. If header tag presents, should not wrap it with `<p>` tag.

In google chrome browser, after adding header tag content, instead of wrap content with `<p>` tag, wrapping it with `<div>`. How to prevent this?

My code:

```
var timeoutReference;
$("#edited_content").keyup(function(e) {
  var code;
  code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code === 13) {
    $("#edited_content").contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
    }).wrap("<p />");
  } else {
    if (timeoutReference) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
    }
    timeoutReference = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#edited_content.publitory").contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
      }).wrap("<p />");
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

While start typing, wrap current line with `<p>` tag and give enter then next line should wrap with `<p>` tag. In my code, I did `setTimeout` for 3 seconds, if stop typing for 3 seconds then wrap that line with `<p>` tag. But my client ask to remove `setTimeout`, he wants to wrap the current line with `<p>` immediately. How to achieve this?

typing html content:

```
test content
<h2>sub content</h2>
content1
```

Resultant html content after wraping it with `<p>` tag:

```
<p>Test content</p>
<h2>sub content</h2>
<p>content1</p>
```

But in chrome browser:

```
<p>test content</p>
<h2>sub content</h2>
<div>content1</div>
```

Comment: Wrap the `div` with other tags.. But not `p` tag.. Try `<div class="div-wrapper">`

Comment: If you're going to save the HTML produced by `contentEditable`, I'd suggest you to manipulate the content just before saving. You have to go through an endless mire, if you'll try to implement a cross-browser "real-time" HTML unifier.

Comment: If you really need real-time uniform HTML, and a third-party library is out of count, I'd suggest you to get familiar with [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range) and [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands). Especially [`execCommad` in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) differs from other browsers, in IE<9 also `Selection/Range` model is totally different. Just good luck with this.