# wrap text with <p> tag while typing the text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Wrap text with <p> tag if that text does not wrap with <p> tag without losing cursor position.

For example:
If I typing "This is a paragraph.." should convert to "<p>This is a paragraph<p>" while typing and the cursor position should not change. The cursor should be at the end of "paragraph". If I start typing, the text should continue after "paragraph".

```
This is a paragrapgh
<h1>header1</h1>
new paragraph
```

Expected hmtl:

```
<p>This is a paragrapgh</p>
<h1>header</h1>
<p>new paragrapgh</p>
```

My code:

```
var timeoutReference;
timeoutReference = void 0;
$("#edited_content.publitory").keyup(function(e) {
  var code;
  code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code === 13) {
    $("#edited_content.publitory").contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
    }).wrap("<p />");
  } else {
    if (timeoutReference) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
    }
    timeoutReference = setTimeout(function() {
      var content;
      content = $("#edited_content.publitory").contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
      }).text();
      $('<p>').text(content);            
      $("#edited_content.publitory").find('div:not([class])').contents().unwrap().wrap('<p/>');
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

In my code, I wrapping text with <p> tag after stop typing for one second. I want to wrap it once start typing.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Are you talking about a <textarea>?

Comment: text should wrap with p tag once I start typing.

Comment: No. Its <div contenteditable=true></div>

Comment: You forgot to post what you tried.

Comment: Looks like a request you are doing without having trying anything yourself, go there then, thank you! https://www.elance.com/q/hire-developer

Comment: @A.Wolff - or http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @j08691 My bad, yours seems better

Comment: You've asked this [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22907411/1169519) just a while ago. Like I said in my comment to that question, format the HTML after user has entered all the text. Implementations of `contentEditable` are differing so much, that practically you'd need to create an own app for every browser to get real-time uniform HTML...

Comment: Yes currently I formatting the content before saving.But the requirement is formatting the content while typing.

Comment: Are you creating a full-featured WYSIWYG editor, or is this just a simple input for a couple of paragraphs? If the latter, you can "mask" [`p`s to look like `div`s](http://jsfiddle.net/E7URR/), most browsers are using `div` anyway...

Comment: Yes @Teemu. Creating full featured WYSIWYG editor. Client requirement is should not use any other editors.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you just want instead:

### DEMO

```
$('div[contenteditable]').on('blur', function(){
    $(this).contents().filter(function(){
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).wrap('<p/>');
});
```

Or like this to strip out any extra spaces:

### DEMO

```
$('div[contenteditable]').on('blur', function(){
    $(this).contents().filter(function(){
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).replaceWith(function(){
        return '<p>' + $.trim(this.nodeValue) + '</p>';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').keydown(function() {
   $('.result').html('<p>' + $(this).val() + '</p>')
})
```

Comment: If I give enter, again the next line should wrap with separate <p> tag